# R script in Power BI returns date as Microsoft.OleDb.Date

Tags: r, date, powerbi

#### The essence:

Why does Powerbi show data of the form `2017-01-04` (`yyyy-mm-dd`) like this?

[image]

---

#### The details

I'm trying to transform a table in Power BI using the `Run R Script` functionality in `Edit Query`.
The source of the table is a csv file with a column with dates of the format `2017-01-04` (`yyyy-mm-dd`):

```
2017-01-04
2017-01-03
2017-01-02
2017-01-01
2016-12-31
2016-12-30
2016-12-29
2016-12-28
2016-12-27
2016-12-26
2016-12-25
2016-12-24
2016-12-23
2016-12-22
```

Using `Get Data`, Power BI shows the same date column like this:

[image]

And after opening the `Edit Query window`, the very same date column still looks like this:

[image]

However, when trying to run an R sctript with the same data, the column only consists of the "values" `Microsoft.OleDb.Date` like this:

[image]

The R script I'm running is simply:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
output <- head(dataset)
```

If I try to change the data type, en error is returned:

[image]

It all seems very strange to me, and I haven't found a reasonable explanation using Google.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For once, the Power BI forum actually had a good answer to an R related problem. Simply change the data type to string format before running the R script. Then you can change back to any date format afterwards. I'll delete the question in a day or two if it doesn't get any attention.

Comment: Post it as an answer and mark it correct. Maybe it will attract an upvote :)

Comment: Glad you didnt delete this question. I needed this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I already provided a solution in the comments, but I'll add a detailed suggestion here as well.

The applied steps in Power BI and the resulting date column should look like this:
[image]

Here are the details:

1. After loading the data from the csv file, go to <kbd>Edit Queries</kbd> and change the data type to text:

[image]

2. Run the R script
3. Change the datatype back to **date** once the script has provided an output.

Answer (score 6):

I wandered upon this answer last week and found that it didn't work for me. I'd receive an error from the R script that "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format." I'm assuming this is due to the many updates that have happened with Power BI in the years since the original answer, because as far as I could tell, all dates were in the exact same format (this error did not occur if I ran the data separately in R/RStudio). I figured I'd leave my solution for those who happen upon this like I did.

I did the exact same thing as vestland's solution, except instead of changing the data type to text, I had to change it to a whole number:

1) Edit query.
2) Convert all date columns to "Whole Number." 
3) Run R Script, and convert date columns from numbers to date:

In R, this requires that you use as.Date() or lubridate::as_date(), with the origin argument, origin = "1899-12-30" to get the correct date when you convert from whole number back to date. (This is the origin instead of "1900-01-01" because Excel/Power BI don't account for two leap years in early 20th century, I've heard.)

Comment: That's Interesting! And yeah, very likely a version issue.