# Operations on multiple tables / datasets with Edit Queries and R in Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi

I have two tables `tbl_A and tbl_B` in a Power BI file that I'd like to transform and analyze using the `Run R Script` functionality in `Edit Queries`.

[image]

This would include handling missing values and joining the tables. However, when starting R, it seems I'm only able to do operations on one table at a time. This is because the `Run R Script` functionality only imports data from the table that is active when you click the `Run R Script` button. This data is then stored in the `dataset` variable.

[image]

If this is correct, it seems to me that the practical use of R` in Power BI would be very limited. I know I could join the tables *before* I unleash R. That would be a feasible solution for a simple case like this, but certainly not for more complex data structures. Any suggestions on how to do operations on **multiple tables with R** in Power BI?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/R-script-with-several-dataframes/m-p/89420#M37588) helps

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I tried it out, but I had no luck with references to multiple datasets. And just as a comment to that particular forum, I think it's a bit strange to call that suggestion a solution.

Comment: Judging by the number of views this post has gotten so far, I'm mostly talking to myself here, but I've finally managed to find a possible solution to this. There are a few quirks to it, but it works. I've written it up as an answer, but please contribute your own answer if you're able to do it a bit more elegantly. Hopefully the PowerBI team at Microsoft will make things a bit easier in the future.

Comment: Please do post that as an answer.  So that others will benefit

Comment: Working on it right now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short version:**

In <kbd>Edit Queries</kbd>, when inserting an R script, just add `[dataset = "Renamed Columns", dataset2 = tbl_A]` in the <kbd>Formula bar</kbd>. In this case `Renamed Columns`  refers to the state of your table (under <kbd>APPLIED STEPS</kbd>) where you're inserting your R script, and `tbl_A` refers to another table that is available to you. And check all your settings with regards to Privacy.

---

**Long version**

Following up on my comment, here is a solution that builds on suggestions from a [business intelligence blog](http://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/08/25/tips-and-tricks-for-r-scripts-in-the-query-editor-in-power-bi/) and contributions in the [PowerBI forum](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-in-query-editor/):

First you'll have to edit a few settings. Go to <kbd>Options and Settings | Options</kbd>. Under <kbd>Privacy</kbd>, select <kbd>Always ignore Privacy Level settings</kbd>. On your own risk of course...

[image]

Now, go to <kbd>Options and Settings | Data Source Settings</kbd>. Select source and click <kbd>Edit permissons</kbd>. Set it to <kbd>Public</kbd>:

[image]

---

Now we're good to go:

I'm gonna go from scratch here since I don't know what quirks any other data loading method would trigger in PowerBI. I've got two separate Excel files, each containing one worksheet called `tbl_A` and `tbl_B`, respectively.
The data for the two tables look like this:

**tbl_A Data**

```
Date        Price1  Price2
05.05.2016  23,615  24,775
04.05.2016  23,58   24,75
03.05.2016  0       24,35
02.05.2016  22,91   24,11
29.04.2016  22,93   24,24
```

**tbl_A Screenshot**

[image]

**tbl_B Data**

```
Date        Price3  Price4
02.06.2016  19,35   22,8
01.06.2016  19      22,35
31.05.2016  19,35   22,71
30.05.2016  15,5    21,85
27.05.2016  19,43   22,52
```

**tbl_B Screenshot**

[image]

---

In the main window in PowerBI, load `tbl_A` using <kbd>Get Data</kbd>:

[image]

Do the same thing with `tbl_B` so that you end up with two separate tables under the <kbd>Fields</kbd> menu:

[image]

Click <kbd>Edit Queries</kbd> under the <kbd>Home</kbd> tab and make sure that the <kbd>Formula Bar</kbd> is visible. If not, you can activate it under <kbd>View</kbd>:

[image]

Depending on how your tables are  loaded, PowerBI will add a few steps in the process. Those steps are visible under <kbd>Query Settings</kbd>:

[image]

Among other things, PowerBI changes the data type of dates to, you guessed it, Date. This can [trigger problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823277/r-script-in-power-bi-returns-date-as-microsoft-oledb-date) later. To avoid this, we can change the data type for date in **both** tables to <kbd>Text</kbd>:

[image]

After you've done this for both tables, make sure tbl_B is active, and have a look at the <kbd>Query Settings</kbd>. You'll se that a new step `Changed Type` has been added in the data loading process:

[image]

We're going to add another step in order to keep our up-coming R script as simple as possible. In that script we're going to join the tables using the `rbind()` function. This will trigger an error unless the column names in the different tables are the same. So go ahead and change the names in column B from `Price3` and `Price4` to `Price1` and `Price2`, respectively:

[image]

Now, the Applied steps under <kbd>Query settings</kbd> should look like this:

[image]

The name of the last step is crucial since you're going to have to reference **Renamed Columns** (or whatever else you'd like to call it) when you write your R script. And finally we can do exactly that.

Under <kbd>Transform</kbd>, click <kbd>Run R Script</kbd>. As the picture below describes, the variable `dataset` will contain the original data for your script. In this case, it will be `tbl_B` in the form of a dataframe if `tbl_B` was the active table when you clicked <kbd>Run R Script</kbd>:

[image]

For now, leave the script as it is,  click <kbd>OK</kbd>, and have a look at the formula bar:

[image]

The picture above tells us two important things. First, we can see that the process has gone smoothly so far and that we have an empty table. Second, we can see that `dataset` refers to `tbl_B` in **the state that we left it after the step** `Renamed Columns`. And this is the part that can be confusing if you've read about these things elsewhere. In the <kbd>Formula bar</kbd>, you can enter a second dataset by adding `, dataset2=tbl_A`, so that the formula now looks like this:

[image]

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Under <kbd>Query Settings</kbd>, you will now see that there's a new step where you can edit your R script:

[image]

Click it to get back into R and add this little snippet:

```
df_B <- dataset
df_A <- dataset2
df_temp <- rbind(df_A, df_B)

output <- df_temp
```

When you click <kbd>OK</kbd>, this is what you'll see:

[image]

Nevermind that the formula bar looks like a mess, just go ahead and click <kbd>Table</kbd> next to <kbd>output</kbd>.

This is it!!

[image]

Go to <kbd>Home</kbd> and click <kbd>Close & Apply</kbd> to get out of the <kbd>Query Editor</kbd>. Now you can inspect the output from your R script under <kbd>Fields</kbd>, or in the <kbd>Data</kbd> tab like in the picture below:

[image]

The end result will be a version of your original `tbl_B` with the columns from `tbl_A` added to it. Not too fancy, but now that you've combined two datasets in you R script you're able to unleash a bigger part of R to your work flow.