# How to change working directory/read from local csv in an R script used as a data source in Power BI?

Tags: r, csv, import, powerbi

I am trying to use an R script as a data source for Power BI. I am a regular user of R but am new to Power BI. When all the datasets that are imported by the R script are from SQL databases I can import the resulting dataframes from the R script fine, however I have  a script that uses a .csv file that Power BI's R session can't find which results in the error:

```
Error: 'times_of_day_grid.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/MyUserName/RScriptWrapper_ac2d4ec7-a4f6-4977-8713-10494f4b0c4f').
```

The .pbix file and the R script are both stored in the same folder as the csv

I have tried manually setting the wd by inserting into the script

```
setwd("C:/Users/MyUserName/Documents/R/Projects/This Project Folder")
```

But this just results in the message

> "Connecting - Please wait while we establish a connection to R"

And later if I leave it running:

> Unable to connect
>
> We encountered an error while trying to connect.
>
> Details: "ADO.NET: R execution timeout. The script execution was
>   terminated, since it was running for more than 1800000 miliseconds."

I have also tried specifying the full addresses of the csv files in read_csv(), but this results in the same timeout warning.

Any ideas as to how I can edit my script (or the settings in Power BI) to get around this? (The script only takes a minute or so to run in RStudio.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can load your csv file using the built-in functionalities in PowerBI `Get Data > Text/CSV` and then go to `Edit Queries` and handle the R scripting from there. That way you won't have to worry about setting the working directory in the R script at all.

You can even load multiple files and work on each and everyone of them using the approach described in [Operations on multiple tables / datasets with Edit Queries and R in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897796/operations-on-multiple-tables-datasets-with-edit-queries-and-r-in-power-bi)

Please let me know how this works out for you-