# R Script is not running in Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi, ado.net

I have seen similar problems to this one but I have not found a solution for this specific case.

**Context**:
I have some excel files imported into Power BI and I need to do some analysis.

**Goal**:
I want to run the following code: `head(my_df,3)`

To achieve that I do the following:
Home -> Transform Data -> Power Query Editor opens -> Click on "my_df" -> "Run R script" -> "output <- head(my_df,3)

This results in the following error message:

> DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: R script error. Error in head(raw_booking,
> 3) : object 'raw_booking' not found Execution halted
>
> Details:
> DataSourceKind=R
> DataSourcePath=R
> Message=R script error. Error in head(raw_booking, 3) : object 'raw_booking' not found Execution halted

I tried head(iris,3) and it worked!!!
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Run R script" takes the input data from the last applied step in the query and stores it as `dataset` in the script window.

Therefore, try:

```
output <- head(dataset, 3)
```

Comment: Wow it works! But how can I refer to other dataframes? For example, I have more than 1 data set, and I would like to take data from there to create a specific table. Is it possible? thanks!

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897796/operations-on-multiple-tables-datasets-with-edit-queries-and-r-in-power-bi