# Python script in Power BI returns date as Microsoft.OleDb.Date

Tags: python, powerbi

After importing a csv file with two columns `[Date, Value]` and transforming it using `Home > Edit Queries > Transform > Run Python Script`, the `Date` column shows `Microsoft.OleDb.Date` instead of dates. Before running the script, the same values in the same column are displayed as `12.10.2018` (input format from csv is `2018-10-12`). This causes any later step in `Query Settings` to break. How do you work around this?

**Sample data:**

```
Date,Value
2108-10-12,1
2108-10-13,2
2108-10-14,3
2108-10-15,4
2108-10-16,5
```

**Code example:**

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
dataset['Value2'] = dataset['Value']*10
dataset
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the same issue as described for R scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823277/r-script-in-power-bi-returns-date-as-microsoft-oledb-date/41942451#41942451), but for the sake of clarity, I'll add an answer for Python in Power BI as well.

**Short answer:**

Just change the `Date` data type from `date` to `Text` before you insert the Python Script.

**The details:**

If you import the csv file using the `Home > Get Data` functionality, and then go to `Home > Edit Queries`, this is what you'll see:

[image]

Before you do anything else, just click on the symbol next to date and select `Text`.

[image]

Now you can click `Run Python Script`,  insert your code and clikc `OK`. This takes you to one last intermediate step where you'll have to click `Table` here:

[image]

This is it:

[image]

Notice that the datatype of `Date` is changed to a date format. If not you can easily change it again with the right-click drop-down menu as explained above.

Comment: I tried this and getting month as date and date as month.